# How to do a loop on a dynamic href link with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, dynamic, href

I would like to make a loop on a dynamic href. Indeed, I download a set of files per page. On each page, I download 100 text files but I have to download 200 000 files. So, I have to click the next button in 2000. To do this, I got the href address of the next button but unfortunately, two objects change in this link, the page number 1,2,3, etc. and a string of characters. Please see attached sample of the next button that changes.

https://search.proquest.com/something/E6981FD6D11F45E8PQ/2?accountid=12543#scrollTo

https://search.proquest.com/something/E6981FD6D11F45E8PQ/3?accountid=12543#scrollTo

https://search.proquest.com/something/61C27022597C4092PQ/4?accountid=12543#scrollTo

https://search.proquest.com/something/E431552DC6554BF7PQ/5?accountid=12543#scrollTo

I'm novel user of Python. My level is bad.

```
#Before I add selenium setup for scraping. 

n=2000

for i in range(1,n):
    href="https://search.proquest.com/something/715376F5A5AF44BBPQ/" + str(i) + "?accountid=12543#scrollTo"
    driver.get(href)

#Here, I add the code which allows downloading for each page.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample link is unavailable for me (i cannot signing up)

First..

> *what is "string of chacracters"*?

book number? or category number?

if it is just random string, i think you should find another way.

How about using [ActionChain](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html)? or [driver.execute_script()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=execute_script#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script)?

First of all, In my opinion, Finding **a meaning of string** (from .js or .html) is more important.

Answer (score 0):

@나민오 I need help in identifying xpath for my next page button. My goal consists to loop through pages in Python Selenium. Please find below the code of the next page button after inspecting on URL page on this picture.

[next page button picture after inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQltP.png)

I try to write the following code in python with selenium to download the file by page.

```
while True:

scraping()          # here I call my function that allows to download the files per page

try:
    #Checks if there are more pages with links
    next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='Page suivante']")
    drive.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_link)
    next_link.click()
     #Time sleep
    time.sleep(20)  
except NoSuchElementException:
    pages_rows= False
```